# Easy way to dump whole website behind a login?

Tags: google-chrome, bash, firefox, wget, curl

With

```
wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension \
     --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains example.com --no-parent example.com
```

can I dump a whole website for offline viewing.

The website I want to dump requires me to login, so I could write a Bash script that saves the cookie and then loads it in again, but it is time consuming.

I suppose Scrapbook for Firefox would be able to do it, but it doesn't run on a modern Firefox.

**Question**

Is there an easy way to dump a whole website that requires login?

Comment: Extracting the cookie once from a browser, then adding it to all request should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [cookie.txt export](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookietxt-export/lopabhfecdfhgogdbojmaicoicjekelh) or [cookies.txt](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiestxt/njabckikapfpffapmjgojcnbfjonfjfg). They even give you the wget command to execute.